# One or more participants failed to draw(), Invalid Column Label

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I have an error that looks like this when I tried to insert a number range filter for my pie chart

One or more participants failed to draw()
Invalid column label:percentage

[How it look likes and there's no error message in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQhcf.png)

I tried to make it look exactly like the example they provided in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls with the only difference in data. The data used in the example is hard-coded while the data I used is directly from MySQL using PHP.

Here is my PHP codes.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("Failed to connect with database");
mysqli_select_db($con, "tutor");

$sql="SELECT * 
FROM googlechart";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$rows = array();
$flag = true;

$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Topics', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')

);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['weekly_task']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['percentage']);
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$table['rows'] = $rows;
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'controls']});

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
                document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

            var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'filter_div',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnLabel': 'percentage'
                }
            });

            var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'PieChart',
                'containerId': 'chart_div',
                'options': {
                    'width': 300,
                    'height': 300,
                    'pieSliceText': 'value',
                    'legend': 'right'
                }
            });
            dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);
            dashboard.draw(data);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="dashboard_div">
    <div id="filter_div"></div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Please advice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the donutRangeSlider's filterColumnLabel.

```
var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter_div',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'percentage'
            }
        });
```

Instead of naming it as 'percentage', it should be '***Percentage***' as follow in the PHP code's column label.

```
$table['cols'] = array(
array('label' => 'Topics', 'type' => 'string'),
array('label' => 'Percentage', 'type' => 'number')
);
```

Solution:

```
var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter_div',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnLabel': 'Percentage'
            }
        });
```